# How to Segue Randomly to ViewControllers in Swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue, uistoryboard

For my Swift app, I'm trying to make it so that a button will lead to a random page in my Main.storyboard but I'm not sure if such a method exists.  Is there a way for me to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "page".  Do you mean "ViewController"?  For instance, do you have 5 "ViewControllers" and you'd like to randomly select one of them?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can segue to a random `ViewController`.  For my example, I chose to use a `UINavigation Controller` and push segues, but you could do this just as easily with other segue types.

I created this Storyboard by:

1. Starting with the *Single View Application* template.
2. Selecting the `ViewController` in the Storyboard and then **Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller** from the Menu.
3. I added 3 more `ViewController`s and set their backgrounds to red, green, and blue in the *Attributes Inspector* on the right.
4. Below I talk about how to wire up the segues from the `ViewController` to the red, green, and blue `ViewController`s.

   Here is an overview of my final Storyboard:

[image: Storyboard showing colored ViewControllers]

The key to making this work is to wire up your segues from the `ViewController` icon at the top of your `ViewController` instead of connecting it from the `UIButton`.  In the pop up, I chose `push` as the segue type.

[image: control drag from ViewController icon]

After that, click on the segue arrow and give the segue an Identifier.  I named mine "pushGreen" because it is a push segue to my green ViewController.

[image: Giving the segue an Identifier]

I repeated this for the red ViewController (segue: "pushRed") and the blue ViewController (segue: "pushBlue").

---

I added a `UIButton` to my first `ViewController` and called it "Go".  Here is the `IBAction` for when it is pressed:

```
@IBAction func goPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let segues = ["pushRed", "pushGreen", "pushBlue"]
    let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(segues.count)))
    let segueName = segues[index]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueName, sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it.  My app is a single-page view, so would this sort of set-up work with it?

Comment: This is intended for picking amongst view controllers in a Storyboard that are connected with segues.  If you are creating your view controllers in a different manner, you'll need to use a different method.