# How can you make an array of segues in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, segue, viewcontroller

I'm trying to make an array in swift of segues so that I can switch to a random view controller via pressing a button.

Comment: Please do add code that shows what you have tried so far and where you failed.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085872/how-to-segue-randomly-to-viewcontrollers-in-swift/27097650#27097650

Answer (score 1):

You can more reasonably maintain an array of strings that could represent the `segue.identifier`.

Comment: I was going to suggest this as well, but Mundi beat me to it. Save an array of strings, fetch one and then use that string to invoke the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method.