# Button in swift to connect to a random storyboard (Xcode version 8.2.1

Tags: swift, xcode

I am new to swift / Xcode and I am trying to create a button in Xcode that can randomly transfer to a different storyboard. I tried following the instructions in this post to do it (I also tried other ideas, but this answer was the most intuitive)

[How to Segue Randomly to ViewControllers in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085872/how-to-segue-randomly-to-viewcontrollers-in-swift)

I've written the IBAction and connected the extra storyboards with different segues to the root view controller but when I start the simulation nothing happens when I click the "go" button. I cannot connect this button with the IBAction by a control drag, so I think that may be the problem.

I've tried creating new projects, connecting the "go" button to the root view controller, and editing the classes (it doesn't let me). What else could be wrong? My code is exactly like the answer to the link I posted. Is there a step missing to that answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you created a custom class for your root view controller. Also make sure you assigned your custom class to the view controller in Interface Builder.

Try dragging from your button to the view controller code pane and let XCode create the IBAction stub for you. Now touching the button should trigger your IBAction.

Comment: I created a new class called "GoButton", but when I go to the identity inspector in the Interface Builder I cannot add the root view controller. The class it says it has is "UITableViewController" and "GoButton" isn't in the drop down menu. So I tried to type it in, but then it refuses to add it. I just added a class by going to file, new file, Cocoa Touch Class, and named it "GoButton" in the subclass of "UIViewController".

Comment: And I just figured out my problem I think. I was putting everything in the subclass of UIViewController when it should have been in the subclass of UITableView Controller.

Comment: Ups, no, the custom class I've mentioned should be a child of UIViewController. It was most probably generated for you already if you used soem XCode template to generate the app. Just make sure you drag from the button in Interface Builder to THAT class, because otherwise it won't work.

Comment: You didn't mentioned any TableView :-) So, if it works now, please don;t forget to accept my answer :-)

Comment: I didn't even realize there was a TableView. I thought UIViewController was the superclass up until now.